# ROC curves and AUC of multiple model combinations in R

Tags: r, roc, auc

[dredge results snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxopK.png)I am using dredge function in MuMin package to come up with multiple factor combinations using logistic regression.

```
library(MuMIn)
AA <- dredge(Forward.model,evaluate = TRUE,rank = "AIC",m.lim = c(8,13),trace=2)
write.xlsx(AA,File location)
```

This results in roughly 10000 different model combinations. Now I want to calculate AUC of all these combinations. Is there a package in R that can do that? I am not very familiar with writing loops in R.

Comment: Can you provide which is the output of `dredge` function? Or how does it look like

Comment: I have edited original post and shared link for output I get from dredge function.

Answer (score 1):

I would follow these steps:

**1)** **For each of the models** obtain the predicted values for each of the samples. Let be `pred.mat` the matrix with the predictions where each row represents an individual an each column different models and `y` the vector with the dichotomoous response variable.

**2)** **Compute the AUC** for each of the models using:

```
    # Load pROC library (install it if not)
      library(pROC)
    # Compute the AUC values
      auc.val <- apply(pred.mat,2,function(x)roc(pred=x,resp=y)$auc)
```

So, `auc.val` will present the AUC values for each of the model.